# How to get image URL from attachment ID and place it in an image src in Wordpress PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm quite new to PHP but my desired functionality is to pull the image attachment URL from it's ID (generated through an ACF Custom Field) and use that as the src for an image.

This is the code that I have right now which should dynamically pull the image URL from the ID but doesn't seem to work:

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( the_field('upload_image') ); ?>`

This is the code that works but isn't dynamic:

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 257 ); ?>`

Note the 257 is the ID of the image - I just need this to be able to be pulled dynamically by appropriating the first code snippet to take that attachment ID from the custom post field (which it should be doing in the first snippet but isn't).

Can anyone help out?

Comment: `the_field` writes to the output buffer directly, you can not use that to pass the value into another function call as parameter. The counterpart of that function that _returns_ the value, is `get_field`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In acf *the_field* just output the item directly. In your case you need to use *get_field* function to get the id of the uploaded image. Because *get_field* returns the item.